# Unable to encode accented characters directly in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, accents

I am trying to type these accented characters directly, without trying to use the built-in LaTeX commands: *ā,ē,ō,ū,ą,ę,ǫ,ų,ṅ,ṡ,ċ,ż* and their uppercase equivalents.

The code compiles alright, when I try to use the following commands:

```
\k{} % for ogonek
\.{} % for the overdot
\={} % for the macron
```

However, when I try directly typing the characters, the file compiles but does not show the accented characters. Instead the following message is displayed:

> ```
> Package inputenc Error: inputenc is not designed for xetex or luatex. >\endinput
> Font shape `T3/ptm/m/it' in size <10> not available(Font)
> Font shape `T3/ptm/m/sl' tried instead
> ```

I am using XeLaTeX as my compiler. Below is the preamble:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,OT2]{fontenc}
```

Comment: xelatex assumes that the input is always utf8. So the inputenc  package should not be used with xelatex

Comment: Is it possible to change my code to be able to type the characters directly?

Comment: Just write them (remove those two packages). Make sure the saved text is UTF8 encoded.

Comment: remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[T1,OT2]{fontenc}` neither package should be used with xetex, accented characters should work automatically if they are in the font.

Answer (score 3):

XeLaTeX already assumes the input is UTF8, so you should not load `inputenc` or `fontenc` under `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\begin{document}
I am trying to type these accented characters directly without trying to use
the built-in LaTeX commands: ā,ē,ō,ū,ą,ę,ǫ,ų,ṅ,ṡ,ċ,ż and their uppercase equivalents.
\end{document}
```

The above example compiles just fine under XeLaTeX.

Comment: This works but then the font reverts to the default if I remove fontenc. Is there a different way to load fonts in xelatex?

Comment: Under pdflatex fontenc does not have much to do with the choice of font. It specifies that non ascii chars are real chars to be found in the font. You might want to look at the fontspec package, but for that you should do some research and perhaps post another question.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!

Comment: For fonts and xelatex, use the `fontspec` package.